# Black screen with Agora and React Native when function gets called after API request

Tags: react-native, live-streaming, agora.io

My app (build with [react native](https://reactnative.dev)) uses [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en) for Video/Audio calling.
I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en) and everything works great when I hardcode my temporary token and app id into my application. However, when I want to retrieve those two variables dynamically via my own server, and call the createAgora function after I retrieved those variables from my server, the screen (and audio) stays black. No error is thrown via log. Everything looks normal. I don't know why this happens.

```
useEffect(() => {
    log('agora mount', channel, role);
    isHost( role === "host" ? true : false );
    connect();
    return destroyAgora;
}, [show]);

const connect = async () => {
    API.get('/api/agora', {})
        .then(function(res){
            if(res.data && res.data.agora.token){

                const app_id = res.data.agora.app_id;
                const token = res.data.agora.token;

                createAgora(app_id)
                .then( () => joinAgora(token) )
                .catch( (err) => log("agora (!) create error: " + err) );

            } else {
                log("agora token error: empty");
            }
        }).catch( (err) => {
            log("agora token error: " + err);
        });
}

const AgoraEngine = useRef<RtcEngine>();

const createAgora = async (app_id:string) => {
    AgoraEngine.current = await RtcEngine.create(app_id);
    AgoraEngine.current.setVideoEncoderConfiguration({ dimensions: {width: 1280, height: 720}, frameRate: 30 });
    AgoraEngine.current.enableVideo();
    AgoraEngine.current.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    const Role = (role === "host" ? ClientRole.Broadcaster : ClientRole.Audience);
    AgoraEngine.current.setClientRole(Role);

    AgoraEngine.current.addListener("JoinChannelSuccess", (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
        isWatching(true);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hey can i get your email/social contact or can I see your code? I'm struggling sice last week intergrating agora

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the code with `then` to join `joinAgora`. In the code below, I created two state variables. utilize a `useEffect` to listen for the `appId` change, `await` for that operation to finish, then call `joinAgora` with the `token`

```
const [appId, setAppId] = useState(null);
const [appToken, setAppToken] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{
   const createThenConnect = async ()=>{
       await createAgora(appId);
       try {
          joinAgora(appToken);
       } catch (ex) {
          log("agora (!) create error: " + ex)
       }
   }
   if (appId !== null) { 
       createThenConnect();
   }
},[appId])

const connect = async () => {
    API.get('/api/agora', {})
        .then(function(res){
            if(res.data && res.data.agora.token){

                setAppId(res.data.agora.app_id);
                setAppToken(res.data.agora.token);
            } else {
                log("agora token error: empty");
            }
        }).catch( (err) => {
            log("agora token error: " + err);
        });
}
```